# SQL Server : Add Comma to the Select statement

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to add comma between **VM.Address** and **VM.City** in the below select query

```
DECLARE @Address NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @Address = ' SELECT  [Address] = CONCAT(VM.Address,' ', VM.City) 

FROM  [dbo].[VendorMaster] VM
    WHERE IsActive = 1 AND VendorID = 6
ORDER BY VendorName'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @Address
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by using comma within quotes in middle of Address and City :

```
set @Address = ' SELECT  [Address] = CONCAT(VM.Address,'+''','''+', VM.City)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set @Address = ' SELECT  [Address] = STUFF(VM.Address + COALESCE(', ' + VM.City, '') , 1, 2, '')
```